# JCheckbox is not showing text in label when being selected

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have a JCheckbox and when clicking the checkbox I want to setText within a label.

So far I have the variables declared and the settings within the frame for the checkbox and the label:

```
JCheckBox chckbxIncludeExt;
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1;


JCheckBox chckbxIncludeExt = new JCheckBox("Include ext");
chckbxIncludeExt.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
chckbxIncludeExt.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.darkShadow"));
chckbxIncludeExt.setBounds(0, 264, 113, 25);
panel.add(chckbxIncludeExt);

JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("");
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(12, 311, 230, 16);
        panel.add(lblNewLabel_1);
```

I have created a class and added an item listener to the checkbox:

```
CheckboxStatus checkboxd = new CheckboxStatus();
        chckbxIncludeExt.addItemListener(checkboxd);
```

This is the class I have created:

```
private class CheckboxStatus implements ItemListener{
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){

            if (chckbxIncludeExt.isSelected()){
                lblNewLabel_1.setText("You have selected the checkbox");
            }



        }
    }
```

This is giving me an error that shows:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.android.apis.appwidget.VFSTool$CheckboxStatus.itemStateChanged(VFSTool.java:199)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireItemStateChanged(Unknown Source)
```

The error is on line 199 where the label sets the text in line 199. When I check the box it shows this and does not show the text.

Comment: how you are setting `chckbxIncludeExt` to `CheckboxStatus` class?

Answer (score 3):

You are shadowing the fields:

```
JCheckBox chckbxIncludeExt;
...
// and later:
JCheckBox chckbxIncludeExt = new JCheckBox("Include ext");
```

Change the later to just:

```
chckbxIncludeExt = new JCheckBox("Include ext");
```

You have the same problem with `lblNewLabel_1`